# Python: How to setup virtuel enviroment?

Tags: python, django, terminal, pipenv, virtual-environment

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment for my Python + Django project, so I ran the following in my terminal:

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

Afterward while being in my folder I tried doing this

```
pipenv install django
```

but I keep getting this error, and I have no idea how to solve it. Not sure if this makes a difference but i work in VScode

**`zsh: command not found: pipenv`**

**Any ideas on how to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

### With venv module

1. Create a virtual environment with venv

```sh
python3 -m venv .venv
```

2. Set as active environment:

```sh
source .venv/bin/activate
```

3. Install django:

```sh
pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python -m pipenv install django
```

Comment: When doing so i get this `No module named pipenv` @FormulaRossa

Comment: replace python with python3. That is required if you have python2 also installed.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job

Comment: Wait, im trying to run `django-admin startproject some_name`and it still gives me this `zsh: command not found: django-admin`@FormulaRossa

Comment: Try: 
`pipenv run django-admin`